# How to rename instances of filepath scattered throughout program based on user input?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java, so apologies if this question seems dumb, I've tried google but there's not really anything on there that matches what I'm looking for.
I am trying to get my program to take in user input and rename .txt files linked to the program with their input. My only issue is, I don't know how I would then take that input and update all the named instances of the filepath across the program. For the most part, I am passing the filepath into methods for usage, but the initial variable of filepath I have declared as a String.
Any advice on the most efficient way to update all instances of this variable at once with the new file name?

```
String filepath = "src/file.txt";
```

Here is the code I currently have for editing the file name:

```
 public static void fileRename(){
        
    String oldFileName = "";
    String newFileName = "";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter old File name: ");
    System.out.println("Formatted as: src/oldFileName.csv");
    oldFileName = in.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter new File name: ");
    System.out.println("Formatted as: src/newFileName.csv");
    newFileName = in.next();


    File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);
    File newFile = new File(newFileName);

    oldFile.renameTo(newFile);

    // sets filepath variable across program equal to newFileName
}
```

Once the user has renamed the file, I am struggling with then updating the filepath variable across the program, as it occurs multiple times within the program.

Comment: `filepath = your_user_input;`? What exactly is the problem you have? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested, that shows the problem you have using the user input to rename files.

Comment: I have updated the post with my current code. I am not having issues with the actul file rename operation, moreso the after part, once the file has been renamed.

Comment: Why is the file path initialized? You requires user to enter old file name during runtime, but that's already initialized. Can you elaborate more on that? Besides, you can always reassign (not mutate) the string during runtime. Did you have any problem in doing so?

Comment: @aceds146 Add `System.out.println()` lines for the values of `oldFileName` and `newFileName` to your question and add the output you get. Also output the return value of `oldFile.exists()`, `oldFile.canRead()`, `oldFile.isFile()`, `newFile.canWrite()`, and `newFile.getParentFile().exists()`. Also, check the return value of `renameTo()` by outputting it with `System.out.println()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String targetExtension = ".txt";
    if (args.length >= 1 ) {
        int extIndex = args[0].lastIndexOf(".");
        if (extIndex != -1) {
            String ext = args[0].substring(extIndex);
            System.out.println(ext);
            if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase(".xml")){
                try
                {
                    File f = new File(args[0]);

                    if (!f.exists())
                    {
                        f.createNewFile();
                    }
                    args[0] = args[0].substring(0, extIndex) + targetExtension;
                    System.out.println(" " + args[0]);
                    File change = new File(args[0]);
                    f.renameTo(change);
                }catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

you can use elseif for all the extension.

Comment: Could you explain what this does?